# How do i check if timezone is present in a unicode string using Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am having timestamp fields in my JSON data where some of the timestamps have timestamp in this format `str("2014-05-12 00:00:00")` and another in this format `str("2015-01-20 08:28:16 UTC")`. I would like to get year, month, day fields only from the string. I have tried the following approach but not sure what is the problem. Can someone please correct me. I have searched some of the answers from StackOverflow but nothing helped me.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_posted=str("2014-05-12 00:00:00")
date_posted_zone=str("2015-01-20 08:28:16 UTC")

def convert_timestamp(date_timestamp=None):
    if '%Z' in date_timestamp:
        d = datetime.strptime(date_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
    else:
        d = datetime.strptime(date_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print convert_timestamp(date_posted_zone)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried following code to search timezone in str and its working.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_posted=str("2014-05-12 00:00:00")
date_posted_zone=str("2015-01-20 08:28:16 UTC")
zone=date_posted_zone.split(" ")
print(zone[2])
def convert_timestamp(date_timestamp=None):
    if zone[2] in date_timestamp:
        d = datetime.strptime(date_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
    else:
        d = datetime.strptime(date_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print convert_timestamp(date_posted_zone)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the literal string `%Z` is in the timestamp value; only `strptime` (and `strftime`) can actually make use of the format character.

What you can do is simply try to parse the string as if it had a timezone, and if that fails, try to parse it without.

```
def convert_timestamp(date_timestamp=None):
    try:
        d = datetime.strptime(date_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
    except ValueError:
        d = datetime.strptime(date_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Of course, as written, you don't really need to parse the string at all; just split it on whitespace and return the first component. (Your existing code already assumes that the year/month/date matches.)

```
def convert_timestamp(date_timestamp):
    return date_timestamp.split()[0]
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question you asked above. Please open a new question if you are having trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil import parser

datetime_no_timezone = parser.parse("2015-01-20 08:28:16")
datetime_with_timezone = parser.parse("2015-01-20 08:28:16+02:00")

if datetime_no_timezone.tz == None:
    # CODE ALWAYS GO THROUGH THIS
    pass

if datetime_no_timezone.tz:
    # CODE ALWAYS GO THROUGH THIS
    pass
```